# What non-security updates are included with "Security Monthly Quality Rollup" KB3185330?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, windows-update, privacy

According to articles by multiple respected technology bloggers, Microsoft's KB3185330 patch for Windows, entitled ***"Security Monthly Quality Rollup"*** actually contains both security and non-security updates.

See:

- https://www.askwoody.com/2016/dont-install-any-updates-yet-but-heres-where-to-find-them/
- http://www.ghacks.net/2016/10/11/microsoft-security-bulletins-october-2016/

There is widespread concern that this update could contain patches that force telemetry onto customers' Windows computers.

What non-security updates are included in this particular ***"Security Monthly Quality Rollup"***?

Comment: is the question now answered or not? Security only = only security updates and Security Monthly Quality Rollup = security + september 2016 rollup KB3185278

Answer (score 0):

The Security Monthly Quality Rollup includes the updates from the [September 2016 update rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3185278):

On the [Security only KB page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3192391), Microsoft writes this:

> ... October 2016 month’s Security Monthly Quality Rollup 3185330, **which
>   additionally includes improvements and fixes from the update that was
>   released in September 20, 2016 - 3185278**.