# Windows 7 May 2017 Updates specific differences?

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-update, patch

For Windows 7, what, *specifically*, is included in the May 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup that is not included in the May 2017 Security Only Quality Update?

Comment: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=may Sort by the Date so you're only getting the latest (5/52017), each update shows great detail. I just prefer using the update catalog for details than the new method Microsoft is pushing.

Comment: [you asked already the same](https://superuser.com/q/1133914/174557) Quality = last month Quality Preview Rollup + Security updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What, specifically, is included in the May 2017 Security Monthly
>   Quality Rollup that is not included in the May 2017 Security Only
>   Quality Update?

The [KB4019264](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019264/windows-7-update-kb4019264) indicates the following

> - This Monthly Rollup update does not include security fixes for
>     Internet Explorer. In order to obtain the security fixes for Internet
>     Explorer, the Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer
>     KB4018271 should also be installed. Note that the Security Monthly
>     Quality Rollup does contain security updates for Internet Explorer.
> - If you use update management processes other than Windows Update and you automatically approve all security updates classifications for
>     deployment, the May 2017 Security-Only Quality Update KB4019263, the
>     May 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup KB4019264, and the Cumulative
>     Security Update for Internet Explorer KB4018271 are deployed. We
>     recommend that you review your update deployment rules to make sure
>     the desired updates are deployed.

Additionally the [KB4019264](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019264/windows-7-update-kb4019264) article indicates:

> This security update includes improvements and fixes that were a part
>   of update KB4015552 (released April 18, 2017) and also resolves the
>   following:
>
> - Addressed issue where, after installing security update KB4015549, applications that use msado15.dll stop working.
> - Updated Internet Explorer 11’s New Tab Page with an integrated newsfeed.
> - Deprecated SHA-1 Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 for SSL/TLS Server Authentication. See Advisory 4010323 for more information.
> - Security updates to Internet Explorer, Microsoft Graphics Component, Windows COM, Microsoft ActiveX, Windows Server, Windows kernel, and
>     Microsoft Windows DNS.

The [KB4019263](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019263) article indicates that:

> This security update includes quality improvements. No new operating
>   system features are being introduced in this update. Key changes
>   include:
>
> - Updated Windows Cryptography API to deprecate SHA-1 for SSL/TLS Server Authentication, including in Microsoft Edge and Internet
>     Explorer 11 . See Advisory 4010323 for more information.
> - Security updates to Microsoft Graphics Component, Windows COM, Microsoft ActiveX, Windows Server, Windows kernel, and Microsoft
>     Windows DNS.

As for the reason a Windows 7 KB article talks about Microsoft Edge, it's simply, they actually used identical verbage for the Windows 10 patch for that bullet.

Comment: Windows 8.1: [KB4019215](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019215/windows-8-update-kb4019215) and [KB4019213](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019213) for anyone interested.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea the reason a Windows 7 KB article has any reference to `Windows 8.1` or `Windows Server 2012 R2` but the quoted statements are the differences between KB4019263 and KB4019264.

Comment: So only bullet 3 and 4 form kbxxx63 update are contained in the security only KBxxxx64 update.

Comment: Thumbs up.  Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

As per Microsoft's release, which you can find [here](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/releasenotedetail/bc365363-f51e-e711-80da-000d3a32fc99)

> The monthly security release includes all security fixes for vulnerabilities that affect Windows 10, in addition to non-security updates.

So the monthly update, includes all updates up until that point, where as the security only update only contains security updates, not bug fixes and improvements.

This is so deployments that automatically approve security grade updates can continue to do so without automatically approving all the updates with each release.

Comment: Author is asking about the Windows 7's Security quality rollup

Comment: @Ramhound actually, they asked about the difference between the two, which I provide.... **So the monthly update, includes all updates up until that point, where as the security only update only contains security updates, not bug fixes and improvements.**

Comment: I didn't have a problem with the rest of your answer, just the part where you linked to the KB article which applies to Windows 10 instead of Windows 7.  *It also seems they wanted more specifics* which wasn't hard to find.